# wpf xml binding parent

Tags: wpf, xml, binding

I have a resource

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="LangData"/>
```

and I can access any data of it like

```
Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource LangData}, XPath=root/eng/sometext}
```

but I have a grid element, and I load an another XAML into the grid in this XAML I want to use the same method

```
Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource LangData}, XPath=root/eng/sometext}
```

but not working what should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you saying that this `XmlDataProvider` is defined inside of a XAML file (say, Window1.xaml) and you want to also be able to use it in another file (say, Window2.xaml)?

Comment: <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="LangData"/>
</Window.Resources>

in the code I add content
XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
d.Load("lang.xml");
var xobj = ((XmlDataProvider)Resources["LangData"]);
xobj.Document = d;

Comment: Finally I made an ugly cheat. Load the new XAML and set it's actual resources. So the XAML root is a Grid. That Grid has that resource, and I set that.